# Change bar color directly in highcharters' hcchart function

Tags: r, highcharts

I'm trying to change the default color of the barplot bars while plotting with hchart() function. From the docs I assumed that adding a "color" argument should work, but the following code produces violet bars instead of black ones.

```
hchart(head(mtcars), "column", x = rownames(head(mtcars)), y = disp, color = '#000000')
```

I can achieve the desired effect by creating the chart using API, however I find using hchart() function really convenient and I'm wondering if the color change is achievable this way.

Comment: In this case color is scaled on a value from predefined gradient. You could see using this code `> myc = seq(from = 0, to = 1000)
> myd = data.frame(y = myc)
> hchart(myd, "column", y = y, color = y)`. Settings options using `highchart() %>% ` is working better - [more info](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html) - maybe you could use that format?

Comment: As @nevrome saids, the hchart function in 0.4.0v is not that clever. I would recommed use the devlopment version which will be released soon  and fix some details. Try this examples http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/questions-41429071

Comment: You can easily do that with `hc_colors` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it, there's an error in the implementation of the function `hchart.data.frame` and the helper functions `get_hc_series_from_df` and `colorize` in the package `highcharter`. The current [github version](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/R/hchart.R) handles this in a very different way, but I think this version is not production ready yet. So for the moment I suggest a very ugly solution:

Change the implementation of `colorize` via `fixInNamespace("colorize", "highcharter")` from

```
function (x, colors = c("#440154", "#21908C", "#FDE725")) 
{
    nuniques <- length(unique(x))
    palcols <- (grDevices::colorRampPalette(colors))(nuniques)
    if (!is.numeric(x) | nuniques < 10) {
        y <- as.numeric(as.factor(x))
        xcols <- palcols[y]
    }
    else {
        ecum <- ecdf(x)
        xcols <- palcols[ceiling(nuniques * ecum(x))]
    }
    xcols
}
```

to

```
function (x, colors = c("#000000", "#21908C", "#FDE725")) 
{
    nuniques <- length(unique(x))
    palcols <- (grDevices::colorRampPalette(colors))(nuniques)
    if (!is.numeric(x) | nuniques < 10) {
        y <- as.numeric(as.factor(x))
        xcols <- palcols[y]
    }
    else {
        ecum <- ecdf(x)
        xcols <- palcols[ceiling(nuniques * ecum(x))]
    }
    xcols
}
```

Comment: This solution works but it is very ugly indeed. Finally the easiest solution for me was to get back to the API notation and doing something like `highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = head(mtcars)$disp, color = '#000000') %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = rownames(head(mtcars)))` It's a bit longish but works with the current stable 0.4.0 version.